# Change Timestamp format in Dataframe

Tags: python, machine-learning, timestamp, time-series

trying to change format of half of Timestamps in dataframe. Any help will be appreciated.
Dataframe is

```
dates = pd.date_range('2000/1/1', periods = 500)
dates = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns = ['Timestamp'])
```

Please help to change format of last 250 elements of timestamp into `%d-%m-%Y`. Dataframe should be of  mixed formats i.e. first 250 of format `%Y-%m-%d` and remaining of format `%d-%m-%Y`.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: did you have a look at [pandas.Series.dt.strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:
`dates.Timestamp[:250].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` and
`dates.Timestamp[250:].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')`